# How do I fold in vim through blank lines (rspec example)?

Tags: vim, folding

I am trying to get vim to fold the way I want, but an having troubles.

I use blank spaces in some of my test code to make it more legible, and I can't get vim to fold through the blank lines.

What I have:

```
describe 'Troubles' do

  describe 'Home' do

    let( :troubles ) { be_over}

    describe 'Pain' do
      it "shouldn't be this hard" { puts "but it is" }
    end
  end
end
```

and it want it to fold like:

```
describe 'Troubles' do

  describe 'Home' do
+--- 6  lines: -------------------
  end
end
```

Any way to get that done?

Here is my .vim setup for folding

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab

set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=10
set nofoldable
set foldlevel=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what folding method are you using?  using an indent fold method works fine for me (well it folds 5 lines since that first one is a blank unindented line.

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

Comment: Thanks or the quick reply Eric.  Actually, I already have that set.  I added my folding and spacing configuration to the question to help clarify.

Comment: I haven't been able to track down how to fix it within the vimrc however I managed to reproduce the problem and fix it at runtime.  If I load those settings in my .vimrc I can reproduce the problem.  If I've reproduced the problem and run :set shiftwidth=2 after the text has already been input, it works as expected but not if i do :set shiftwidth=2 before the text has been input.  Similarly if the file has been saved and reopened, the shiftwidth=2 in .vimrc works and the fold works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in folding for RSpec files specifically, here's [a little RSpec foldexpr plugin](https://github.com/rlue/vim-fold-rspec) I threw together over the weekend. It's big for what it does (~150 SLOC), but it handles folding just the way I like it (*e.g.,* folds subsume trailing newlines after a block, which was not exactly your question, but pretty close).

Here's a foldcolumn for your sample code:

```
-    describe 'Troubles' do
|
|-     describe 'Home' do
||
||       let( :troubles ) { be_over}
||
||-      describe 'Pain' do
|||        it "shouldn't be this hard" { puts "but it is"}
|||      end
||     end
|    end
```

and here's what it would look like folded:

```
describe 'Troubles' do

- describe 'Home' ---------------------------------------------------- [4] -
end
```